# I'm getting this error trying to convert rails application from development mode to production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, node-modules

I'm trying to convert rails application from development mode to production mode

when apply the command to precompile the assets which will copy  js,css  file to public folder

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/enzyme/index.d.ts:367:40
    TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.

i'm getting above error

Comment: You need to add much more details as this is totally unclear. What tools do you use?

Comment: i am trying to make changes in manageiq which ruby based platform.i want to convert development mode into production mode

Comment: try it again after "npm update"

Comment: i did update but doesn't work